# MySQL rearrange query structure

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to display a chart based on a query I built in dbForge Studio but its not charting correctly because I think its only selecting 1 axis of data.

The query is displaying the result like so:

```
column1  column2  column3
data      data     data
```

I guess to properly display the chart, I would need it in a format like this:

```
Type      Total
column1    data
column2    data
column3    data
```

Here is the query below. How do I add in the virtual columns like so and rearrange this?

```
    SELECT 
      (SELECT COUNT(T1.APP_UID)
       FROM TABLE1 T1 
       WHERE T1.APP_STATUS = 'To_Do' ) AS 'Column1' ,

      (SELECT COUNT(T1.APP_UID)
       FROM TABLE1 T1 
       WHERE T1.APP_STATUS = 'Completed' ) AS 'Column2' ,

      (SELECT COUNT(T1.APP_UID)
       FROM TABLE1 T1 ) AS 'Column3'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, if you need a 2-column, N-rows set of data, your query should have two arguments after "SELECT". And if you need to put results from the upward SQLS into the chart, you should use UNION or UNION ALL (read http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html for more info)  like this:

```
(SELECT 'Type', 'Total' FROM DUAL)
UNION [ALL]
(SELECT 'column1', COUNT(T1.APP_UID)
       FROM TABLE1 T1 
       WHERE T1.APP_STATUS = 'To_Do' )
UNION [ALL]
(SELECT 'column2', COUNT(T1.APP_UID)
       FROM TABLE1 T1 
       WHERE T1.APP_STATUS = 'Completed' )
UNION [ALL]
(SELECT 'column3', COUNT(T1.APP_UID)
       FROM TABLE1 T1 )
```

But from what I see, you could just use the following to get similar results (count of apps that have one of two statuses ("completed, to_do"), and sum of all apps. The code below assumes that there is only one entry for each app status in the table):

```
(SELECT T1.APP_STATUS, COUNT(*) FROM TABLE1 T1 WHERE (T1.APP_STATUS = 'To_Do' OR T1.APP_STATUS = 'Completed') GROUP BY T1.APP_STATUS)
UNION ALL
(SELECT 'Altogether', COUNT(T1.APP_UID)
       FROM TABLE1 T1)
```

Comment: i did revise it a little as i didn't like the wording of one of the statuses so i did this instead: (SELECT 'Routed' AS 'Type',
          COUNT(T1.APP_UID) AS 'Total'
   FROM TABLE1 T1
   WHERE (T1.APP_STATUS = 'Completed')
   GROUP BY T1.APP_STATUS)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUM(T1.APP_STATUS = 'To_Do') FROM T1
UNION SELECT SUM(T1.APP_STATUS = 'Completed') FROM T1
UNION SELECT COUNT(*) FROM T1
```